# Which flashes are weather-proofed?

Tags: flash, weather

With some effort, it's possible to find out which camera models and lens have weather sealing. However, there seems to be little information available on weather-sealed flashes.

From [another answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3842/picking-a-hotshoe-flash/3844#3844) I got a hint that Canon 580EX is weather-proofed. Are there any others known?

Comment: The [SB-700](http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Product/Flashes/4808/SB-700-AF-Speedlight.html) and [SB-900](http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Product/Flashes/4807/SB-900-AF-Speedlight.html) offer an optional "Drip-Proof Mounting Foot Cover (Water Guard)"

Comment: I find it quite interesting that Nikon sells rain-covers for flash feet without making any claims for weather resistance of the flash itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK, it's the [580EX II](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/speedlite_flash_lineup/speedlite_580ex_ii), to be specific. None of the others in the current Canon lineup appear to have that. Nikon, Pentax, and Sony don't appear to have an option, though Nikon offers a water guard for their flashes. That seems like more of a compromise than anything. On the 3rd party front, Sigma is out (I have one and know) and I can't find any evidence that Metz has a weather sealed option and I know the current top of the line doesn't, so that also indicates.

Beyond that, I don't know, but that covers a lot of ground. Net effect, I think that if you want to seal it, it's the old plastic bag for the vast majority of them...

Comment: I seem to remember from its introduction, but do not positively know, that the 580 mk II is only actually weatherproof if mounted on a 1D/1Ds mk III or IV. Possibly the 7D as well. Not just any old hotshoe, anyway.

Comment: @Staale - The camera must also be weather sealed for the whole thing to mean much. Otherwise you may still have issues on the shoe itself.

Comment: Yeah... but the 1Ds mk II, for instance, is weather-sealed as such but I think it leaves the hotshoe less protected with a 580 II than a 1D III does. So you can have a sealed flash (580 II) on a sealed camera (1Ds II) but have the total system un-sealed because the hotshoe is not protected.

Comment: @Staale - Sure, all you're saying is that the 1DS mk II may not be completely weather sealed. Nevertheless, as far as I can tell, there's only one option for a flash that is and so combined with a full weather sealed cam you're in good shape. Is there something else you're trying to say? The OP didn't ask about cameras.

Comment: No, John, the 1D/Ds marks I and II are completely weather-sealed, to the very best of Canon's ability. You can pretty much use them in the shower. Surely you must know this? But for the join with the equally weather-sealed 580 EX II to be weather-sealed the camera body around the flash-shoe must be designed in a particular way to fit the flash snugly, the 1D/Ds marks III and IV have this design and marks I and II do not.

Comment: Hence, the sum total of a 1D I/II plus 580 EX II will not be weather-sealed while a mk III/IV plus 580 II will be. A sealed camera plus a sealed flash does not necessarily equal a sealed camera system. That's what I am saying - one must consider more than the sum of the individual parts, there is a system integration issue here as well.

Comment: @Staale - Fine, feel free to add to my answer if you like, but I was answering what flashes are sealed, not what cameras are prepared to make use of it. So if you feel the OP needs that as well, cool.

Comment: Thanks, I think pointing out the weak spot at connection of two sealed systems is quite important in practice.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps an overkill, but **underwater strobes** should be more than weather-proof. They don't seem to be mountable on hotshoe (which seems to be hard to make waterproof), so they are for off-camera use only (intended for use on bracket). Some of them support TTL.

Nikon [SB-102, SB-103, SB-105](http://www.nikonlinks.com/unklbil/speedlights.htm#sb102) and SB-104 seem to be discontinued.

For example, [Inon](http://www.inon.jp/products/lineup.html) S-2000, Z-240, D-2000 seem to be currently offered universally TTL-capable models. [Seacam](http://www.seacam.com/en/products/flash-unit) 150D supports Canon e-TTL and Nikon i-TTL. Olympus  has [UFL-1](http://www.olympus-europa.com/consumer/198_ufl-1_underwater_flash.htm) and [UFL-2](http://www.olympus-europa.com/consumer/198_digital_slr_ufl-2_19296.htm) capable of wireless TTL with Olympus cameras. [SeaLife Digital Pro](http://www.sealife-cameras.com/accessories/digital_pro_flash.html) has an Auto Mode.

Underwater Photography Guide has an extensive [Underwater Strobe Chart](http://www.uwphotographyguide.com/underwater-photography-strobes).

Answer (score 1):

Now Pentax has 2 WR flashes both of the new 360 and 540 fgz versions (II) are weather sealed. But i did use my Sigma 610 DG Super in some rainy weather and i really have no fear to do it again. (Cover the hotshoe with playdoh.)